# SCM Manager - creating new repository groups

Tags: scm

We're using SCM Manager as a web front end to Mercurial. All our repositories are grouped into "main" but looking at this screenshot from the website:

[image: SCM Manager]

I see that it's possible to have other groups. I've done a bit of Googling but can't find anywhere that says how to create these groups.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, it turns out, is when you create a repository, just prefix the repository name with "groupname/" where groupname is the name of your group.